# Script runs with ISE but not via PowerShell console

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have a script that runs smooth with ISE but stops when running via PowerShell console. Error raised:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

So here is the code sample (can't show it all):

```
$global:mainForm.Text= $global:mainForm.text.substring(0,$global:mainFormTitleSize)+" || Save File Name = ..."+$outputFileName.substring($outputFileName.length - $decalage,$decalage)
```

I ran ISE with debug to check every variables and everything is not null.
But when I execute via the PowerShell console, the property `$global:mainForm.Text` is empty. Even if it is set few lines above and never touched in between.

**Edit :**
With some more digging, I noted that `mainForm` is not declared as `$global:` but just as a simple variable.

Could it be part of the issue ? (I'm quite new to ps and it's not my script so I don't know much what to expect)

**Edit:** (01/02/2022)
I think some point, I set PowerShell as default program to open .ps1 files.
Since then, I couldn't see the option "Run with PowerShell" in the contextual menu, I could just clic "open" or "open with" then "Windows PowerShell".

So, when I clic "open", I got the error I described above.
When I clic "open with Windows PowerShell", a whole new set of errors showed up. So still not functioning.

Now I got the idea to set back default program to Notepad.
The "run with PowerShell" is back AND functional.
The "open with Windows PowerShell" got the error.

I don't get it.

Comment: ISE itself runs Powershell as well. Just to clarify, I assume you are referring to the Powershell console (the "place" where the issue appears)?

Comment: @EduardUta, first case : right click > Run with PowerShell => error //

second case : right click > edit (open ISE) > run with ISE => all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Torino,

The ISE loads some assemblies automatically that the Shell does not.
I include the following code in all my code that uses forms to make sure that where ever it is run it works properly.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"

If ($host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost' -or
    $host.Name -eq 'Visual Studio Code Host') {

  try{  <#+------------------------------------------------+
          | Check that the proper assemblies are loaded    |
          | for using XAML forms.                          |
          | Required for PS Console and Visual Code, while |
          | only Systems.Windows.Forms needed for PSISE!   |
          +------------------------------------------------+
        #>
    $ATArgs = @{AssemblyName = "PresentationCore",
                               "PresentationFramework",
                               "WindowsBase"
                ErrorAction = 'Stop'}
    Add-Type @ATArgs
  } 
  catch {
    $Message = 
        "Failed to load Windows Presentation Framework" +
        " and/or other assemblies required for this program!"
     & $TermMsg
    Exit 
  }
  
} #End If ($host...
```